# Every modular right ideal is contained in a modular maximal ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

If $R$ is a ring, possibly without $1$, a right ideal $\mathfrak{a}$ of $R$ is **modular** if there exists $e\in R$ such that $r-er\in \mathfrak{a}$ for all $r\in R$. So $e$ is a left identity mod $\mathfrak{a}$.

In Lam's book *A First Course In Noncommtative Rings*, exercise 4.5(a) says that every proper modular right ideal $\mathfrak{a}$ of $R$ is contained in a modular *maximal* right ideal $\mathfrak{m}$. (To be clear: $\mathfrak{m}$ should be a maximal right ideal which just happens to be modular.)

I also found the following quote in the [wikipedia article for regular ideal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_ideal):

> *Somewhat surprisingly, it is possible to prove that even in rings without identity, a modular right ideal is contained in a maximal right ideal.*

But this article doesn't specify that the maximal ideal is modular.

How do you solve Lam's exercise? I've tried Zorn's Lemma: if $Z$ is the set of proper modular right ideals containing $\mathfrak{a}$, then $Z$ is nonempty since $\mathfrak{a}\in Z$. Suppose $\{\mathfrak{b}_i\}$ is a chain in $Z$. Probably a candidate for an upper bound is the union $\mathfrak{b}:=\bigcup \mathfrak{b}_i$. This is a right ideal, but I'm not sure why it's proper or modular though. In the unital case one can conclude $\mathfrak{b}\subsetneq R$ because $1\notin \mathfrak{b}$. But I don't know how to adapt this to the nonunital case.

Is this the wrong approach?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If $\mathfrak{a}$ is a modular right ideal, then every right ideal $\mathfrak{b}$ containing $\mathfrak{a}$ is modular as well, because $r-er\in\mathfrak{a}$ implies $r-er\in\mathfrak{b}$.

Note also that $e\notin\mathfrak{a}$, if $\mathfrak{a}$ is a proper ideal.

Applying Zorn's lemma is indeed the way to go. Consider the family of right ideals containing $\mathfrak{a}$ and *not* containing $e$, ordered by inclusion.

The union of a chain in this family is a (modular) right ideal containing $\mathfrak{a}$ and not containing $e$; so Zorn's lemma provides a maximal member of the family, $\mathfrak{m}$.

Suppose a right ideal $\mathfrak{b}$ properly contains $\mathfrak{m}$; then $\mathfrak{b}$ contains $\mathfrak{a}$ and, by maximality of $\mathfrak{m}$ it must also contain $e$. Therefore $\mathfrak{b}=R$.

Comment: Right. Woops --- I was thinking $r-er\in \mathfrak{a}$ for all $r\in \mathfrak{a}$, not all $r\in R$ (even though that's what I wrote above ...) Thanks.

Comment: @Ehsaan Note that a right ideal which is maximal among the modular right ideals is maximal, because of the result above, so talking of “maximal modular right ideal” is not ambiguous.